# Garbage collector in c for variables inside a loop

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am mainly a Java person recently working on some projects involving C so please bear with me if it's a basic C question.

So inside my main I have a while loop and I declare a variable each iteration.

```
int main()
{
  int done = 0;
  while(!done)
  {
    char input[1024];
    scanf("%s", input);
    //parse the input string
    ...
  }
}
```

Now since the input variable will change every time depending on what the user wants I have to use a "new" variable each time. However, I think the above declaration will be causing memory leak ultimately(or will it?). I would like to know if gcc takes care of garbage collection.

Is there any better approach without allocating and freeing after every iteration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think the above declaration will be causing memory leak ultimately(or will it?).

No, it wouldn't: `input` is an *automatic* (AKA "Stack") variable, it will get "deallocated" as soon as it goes out of scope (i.e. after the closing brace).

> Is there any better approach without allocating and freeing after every iteration?

There is no actual allocation or deallocation going on: the space in the automatic memory (AKA "on the stack") is allocated by some compile-time bookkeeping around the stack pointer. The access of automatic variables is a very fast operation heavily assisted by hardware, so there is no loss of efficiency there.

Dynamic memory allocation (Java-style) is done with `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` in C. These are not garbage collected - you need to explicitly `free` every pointer that you allocated.

Comment: might be worth mentioning dynamic allocation, as i think thats what he wants

Comment: @MichaelBrown Thanks - I edited the answer to mention dynamic allocation.

Comment: So using memory directly from the stack is *always* faster than dynamically allocating memory?

Comment: @MichaelBrown, no I don't think "that is what he wants". And the remark on `malloc` etc now is even obfuscating the answer :( The clear message here is that the method in the question is safe and efficient, everything you want.

Comment: @Aposperite, in this case here where you don't even initialize that array: yes, it is  usually faster or at least as fast. There is no function call and only very rudimentary bookeeping involved for arrays that are allocated "on the stack".

Comment: @Aposperite "Always" is a very strong qualifier, and "faster" is unnecessarily broad, but in all implementations that I've seen stack allocation and deallocation happened significantly faster than comparable dynamic allocations and deallocations.

Comment: On any sane implementation, "allocation" of automatic variables is O(1), i.e. the amount of time to allocate 1 `char` and the amount of time to allocate 10000 large structs (assuming they even fit) are identical.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I think the above declaration will be causing memory leak ultimately(or will it?)

It will not. The `input`object is discarded every time the trailing `}` of the loop is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

As other have already said, stack variables are automatically freed when they go out of scope and are usually overwritten soon.

That being said, the reason I'm writing this answer is to stress this: **there is no garbage collector in C**, at least not by default. This means that *heap* allocated memory (usually initialized with `malloc`, `calloc` and others) must be manually freed by you (using `free`).